# JavaScript error for custom list button: 'Syntax error in regular expression'

Tags: javascript, custom-object, urlhacking

I have a custom Opportunity list button. I have placed this button on the Opportunity related list on the contract record.

The JavaScript is:

```
/006/e?retURL=%2F{!Contract.Id}&accId={!Contract.AccountId}&ctrcid={!Contract.Id}
```

I am returning this error when I click the button:

> A problem with the OnClick JavaScript for this button or link was 
>   encountered: Syntax error in regular expression

I don't see anything wrong with this snippet. Can you advise?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made the button the wrong type. You should be redirecting to a url rather than executing Javascript.

Comment: Thank you! I changed it to a URL instead of having it execute JavaScript.

Comment: @AndyHitchings No problem. Glad to help.